# writing or saving the printf command to a text file (c programming)

Tags: c

How can I save/write the printf content to a text file?

Ive use puts() but it didnt work.

Is there other comment that I can used?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    /*declare and initialise variable*/
    char message[32][114],buffer[114];
    int i=1;
    FILE *input_file;
    FILE *output_file;

    input_file=fopen("exon11.txt", "r");
    output_file=fopen("1.txt", "w");

    /*stores and prints the data from the string*/
    while(fgets(buffer,114,input_file))
        {
            strcpy(message[i],buffer);
            /*fputs(message[i],file_out);*/
            printf(">%d\n%s\n\n",i,message[i]);
            i++;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

thank you in advanced

Comment: If you want to write to a file, then use `fprintf`, `fputs`, `fputc`, etc..  These functions all accept a `FILE *` by which you tell them which file should receive the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fprintf` to write data in file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    /*declare and initialise variable*/
    char message[32][114],buffer[114];
    int i=1;
    FILE *input_file;
    FILE *output_file;

    input_file=fopen("exon11.txt", "r");
    output_file=fopen("1.txt", "w");

    /*stores and prints the data from the string*/
    while(fgets(buffer,114,input_file))
        {
            strcpy(message[i],buffer);
            /*fputs(message[i],file_out);*/
            fprintf(output_file,">%d\n%s\n\n",i,message[i]);
            i++;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ive tried your suggestion but the output text file is blank. Do I have to wait for a longer time for the data to be written in the text file?

Comment: someone also suggested to me to try this command "MyProgram > result.txt". Where should I put this syntax?

Comment: What's inside of 'exon11.txt' file?

Comment: A sequence of DNA character. contain 3426 DNA character

Comment: @dayanasaiful, Is that data printing on console if you use printf(message[i]) ?

Comment: Yes. It is printed in the pop up block box